# How do I get two lists together in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am generating two tables using the `table` command in `R`.  I want to make a table/dataframe/matrix such that all the names from both the tables are represented and proper 'zero' counts are included in the output. e.g.

The data I currently have looks something as follows

Table 1

```
A   B   C
1   2   4
```

Table 2

```
C   D   E
3   4   4
```

I would like to have output that is as follows:

```
    Table1 Table2
A        1      0
B        2      0
C        4      3
D        0      4
E        0      4
```

How can I do this in R?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

without reshape:

```
t1 <- table(c("A", rep("B", 2), rep("C", 4)))
t2 <- table(c(rep("C", 3), rep("D", 4), rep("E", 4)))

ndf <- merge(t1, t2, by = "Var1", all = TRUE)
ndf[is.na(ndf)] <- 0
ndf
  Var1 Freq.x Freq.y
1    A      1      0
2    B      2      0
3    C      4      3
4    D      0      4
5    E      0      4
```

Answer (score 3):

Ignoring what I think is a typo in your question (the C frequencies should be 4 and 3, right, not 2 and 3?) you can do this by coercing to data frames and then merging:

```
t1 <- table(rep(LETTERS[1:3],times=c(1,2,4)))
t2 <- table(rep(c("C","D",'E'),times=c(3,4,4)))
merge(as.data.frame(t1),as.data.frame(t2),by="Var1",all=T)
```

and then converting the NAs to zeros.

Answer (score 2):

DATA

```
dat <- list(rep(LETTERS[1:3],times=c(1,2,4)),rep(LETTERS[3:5],times=c(3,2,2)))
```

CODE

```
f <- function(d){
       lev <- unique(unlist(d, use.names=FALSE))
       d <- lapply(d, factor, levels=lev)
       r <- do.call(cbind, lapply(d, table))
       colnames(r) <- paste("Table", seq(NCOL(r)), sep="")
       return(r)
     }
```

OUTPUT

```
f(dat)
  Table1 Table2
A      1      0
B      2      0
C      4      3
D      0      2
E      0      2
```

Comment: Nice way of demonstrating how to write (and use) a function in R.

Comment: Hi! This is a nice solution and a good demonstration.  Thank you.